# Hypothesis testing on a Bernouilli variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bernoulli-distribution

I have a Bernouilli variable which is $1$ with probability $p$. I need to test the hypothesis $H_0:p<\theta$ vs. $H_1:p>\theta$, where $\theta$ is a given constant. The question is to find $n$ such that the test can conclude $H_0$ with a probability $\alpha$ of error.

I understand that after $n$ drawings, the number of $1$'s, let $m$, follows a Binomial law $B(m;n,p)$; it can be approximated by a Poisson or Normal law under some conditions on $n$ vs. $p$ (my $p$ is small). I also understand that the test will conclude $H_0$ when $\text{cdf}_B(m;n,\theta)<\alpha$.

But my unknown is $n$. How can I choose it, either using the exact model or the approximations ?

This is not a homework but a real-world question (quality control). $\theta=0.001, \alpha=0.9$.

Comment: Suppose $n$ = 10000 and $m$ = 10. Will you reject or accept $H_0$?

Comment: @user158565: no idea if that satisfies the $90\%$ risk. It's my question.

Comment: It seems you have two questions. 1) what statistical test will be used and 2) n=?. Need to get the answer to 1), then working on 2).

Comment: @user158565 Let the test be $\text{cdf}_B(m;n,\theta)<\alpha$.

Comment: I know how to test simple null hypothesis. But your null hypothesis is composite, so I have no idea.